# How to take pictures from a digital camera remotely using python...capture.py?

Tags: python-2.6

I would like to take pictures with my Nikon Coolpix and Nikon D5000 digital camera remotely with python.

I have downloaded all the packages from `pyusb`.

When I run the capture.py script, the following error results:

```
"Attribute Error:  'module' object has no attribute 'findptps'"
```

The line of code the error is referring to is here in capture.py:

```
ptpTransport = PtpUsbTransport(PtpUsbTransport.findptps()[0])
```

What is this error caused by?  Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably done:

```
import PtpUsbTransport
```

instead of:

```
from PtpUsbTransport import PtpUsbTransport
```